# Solve the following differential equation using power series :$(x-1)y''+xy'+\frac yx=0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, problem-solving

I was learning to solve differetial equations, using power series. There was a problem given as:

Solve the following differential equation using power series :$$(x-1)y''+xy'+\frac yx=0.$$

I tried solving the problem in the following way:

> Assuming, $y=\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n$ to be a solution of $(x-1)y"+xy'+\frac yx=0.$ Now, $y'=\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty n c_nx^{n-1}$ and $y''=\Sigma_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1) c_nx^{n-2}.$ Substituting these in the given equation, we get, $$(x-1)\Sigma_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1) c_nx^{n-2}+x\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty n c_nx^{n-1}+\frac 1x\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n=0\implies x\Sigma_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1) c_nx^{n-2}-\Sigma_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1) c_nx^{n-2}+x\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty n c_nx^{n-1}+\frac 1x\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n=0\implies \Sigma_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1) c_nx^{n-1}-\Sigma_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1) c_nx^{n-2}+\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty n c_nx^{n}+ \Sigma_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^{n-1}=0.$$ Reindexing the summations we get, $$\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)(n+1) c_{n+2}x^{n+1}-\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)(n+1) c_{n+2}x^{n}+\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) c_{n+1}x^{n+1}+ \Sigma_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^{n-1}=0.$$ Again, $$\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)(n+1) c_{n+2}x^{n+1}-\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)(n+1) c_{n+2}x^{n}+\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) c_{n+1}x^{n+1}+ \Sigma_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^{n-1}=0\implies \Sigma_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)(n) c_{n+1}x^{n}-\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)(n+1) c_{n+2}x^{n}+\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty (n) c_{n}x^{n}+ \Sigma_{n=-1}^\infty c_{n+1}x^{n}=0\implies \Sigma_{n=1}^\infty [(n+1)(n) c_{n+1}x^{n}- (n+2)(n+1) c_{n+2}x^{n}+(n) c_{n}x^{n}+ c_{n+1}x^{n}]+2c_2+\frac {c_0}{x}+c_1=0.$$  Now, the right-hand side of the equation is free of $x^{-1}$ term due to which, $c_0=0.$ So,  $ \Sigma_{n=1}^\infty [(n+1)(n) c_{n+1}x^{n}- (n+2)(n+1) c_{n+2}x^{n}+(n) c_{n}x^{n}+ c_{n+1}x^{n}]+2c_2+\frac {c_0}{x}+c_1=0\implies  \Sigma_{n=1}^\infty [(n+1)(n) c_{n+1}- (n+2)(n+1) c_{n+2}+(n) c_{n}+ c_{n+1}]x^n+2c_2+c_1=0.$ Now, comparing LHS and RHS of the equation, we can say that $2c_2+c_1=0$ and $ (n+1)(n) c_{n+1}- (n+2)(n+1) c_{n+2}+(n) c_{n}+ c_{n+1}=0.$ Thus, $c_2=-\frac{c_1}{2}.$ For $n\geq 1,$ we have, $ (n+1)(n) c_{n+1}- (n+2)(n+1) c_{n+2}+(n) c_{n}+ c_{n+1}=0\implies (n^2+n+1) c_{n+1}- (n+2)(n+1) c_{n+2}+n c_{n}=0\implies -(n^2+n+1) c_{n+1}+(n+2)(n+1) c_{n+2}-n c_{n}=0\implies (n+2)(n+1) c_{n+2}-(n^2+n+1) c_{n+1}-n c_{n}=0.$

I don't know how to proceed further since, the equation $ (n+1)(n) c_{n+1}- (n+2)(n+1) c_{n+2}+(n) c_{n}+ c_{n+1}=0,$ is a recurrence relation though, but how to find the coefficient $c_n$ here ? I am not getting, how to solve this recurrence relation in order to find $c_n$? (I am just a beginner and I need an elementary level explanation of this.) I am skeptical , whether at all a power series solution exists or not. (I found this problem in a handout, so I don't know about the source. If anyone does know about it, please do let me know.)

There might be several posts, concerning the same topic, but I can't seem to find it either.

*My attempt is modified after Elliot Yu's beautiful suggestion*

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144661/discussion-on-question-by-franklin-solve-the-following-differential-equation-usi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

You have gotten quite far with the method actually, by plugging in the ansatz $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$ and simplifying, and seem to be aware of what to do next, namely deriving a recurrence relation for $c_n$ and ultimately solving it for the series coefficients. Where you are stuck seems to be at the step of "collecting like powers of $x$ and equating the coefficients to zero", as indicated by your observation "the powers of $x$ aren't alike". Thus I would like to address this step specifically.

With a sum like $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^{n-1}$ (the last term), we can actually rearrange it into a sum where the general term is expressed in terms of $x^n$ rather than $x^{n-1}$ by shifting the indices. Substitute $n - 1$ by $n$, i.e. make the transformation $n\mapsto n + 1$, the general term $c_n x^{n-1}$ becomes $c_{n + 1} x^n$, and the lower bound becomes $n = - 1$ while the upper bound is still $n\to \infty$. This gives us the sum $\sum_{n=-1}^\infty c_{n+1} x^{n}$. (If this manipulation is confusing, think of it as a two-step process, first a substitution $n = m + 1$, and then relabeling the new dummy variable $m$ as $n$ again. You can also check the first few terms of each sum to see that they are indeed the same.) The same can be done for the first and third terms, namely shifting the power of $x$ down by $1$, by shifting the index $n\mapsto n-1$.

The only thing you need to watch out for are the $x^{-1}$ and $x^0$ terms in the sum, because now the sums don't have the same lower bounds, so the initial cases of the recurrence relation will be different. However, this is precisely what you will need to solve for $c_0$ and $c_1$, the initial conditions needed to solve the second order recurrence relations for all the coefficients.

Comment: You can't just plugin standard power series before determining if the point you are expanding around is an ordinary point or regular singular point or even irregular singular point. This should be the very first step to do in solving any ode using series methods.

Comment: @Elliot Yu Any ideas you might want to suggest on how to proceed after this ?

Comment: @NasserAs I mentioned earlier, this course is completely new to me. Forgive me for my ignorance, but I don't get a word you are sayjng. Maybe, the thing you are pointing out is more than justified, but I have no idea about it. In our college, it's just taught as a *mechanical, problem solving tactics* i.e they go on saying "If you have a differential equation, then you can obtain a power series solution by this method: first consider the ansatz..." and shockingly, its taught just at the start of the course after letting us know, what a differential equation is and

Comment: @Nasser      what are the types of differential equations. This is just the introduction and nothing else is mentioned. After that, **they straight away move to finding power series solution.**  I hope I am able to picture out my situation to you. I am quite helpless here.